# Select window and don't select textareas?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to attach an event for pressing the enter key on the whole window(or body), but i want to keep the enter event for textarea ( to get a new line ) .

I tried something like

```
$(window).not(':textarea') , $('body:not(textarea)')
```

And i tried something like this

`$('*').filter(function(arg1, arg2) { !$(arg2).is('textarea').on('keydown', 
$.proxy(this.nextStep, this)); });` but this gave me an error .

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the keydown event bubbles, so you can attach it to the window without affecting the textarea.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/aCTTq/

Although if you run `preventDefault` on the event object in the handler you will have a problem. In that case try something like:

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    if ( e.target.nodeName != 'TEXTAREA' ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aCTTq/1/

Comment: Works on Chrome and FF .